# Trying to make a "start - stop" recorder by occurrence of an event in python

Tags: python, pyaudio

Suppose I define a square shaped region with its vertices as coordinates on my screen (it's a touch screen), and if I touch there, a "click" event occurs, prompting my program to start recording audio using modules like pyaudio and wave. I have zero knowledge with PyAudio (although I did check a code which records audio simply for 5 seconds and it start stops on its own which is here: https://gist.github.com/mabdrabo/8678538) and I'm hoping I can get the gist of it by the answer to this question.

I'll need help with both - How to exactly know that I touched or clicked (assuming a touch and a mouseclick are treated as the same on Windows 10), and IF that happens, how to start recording, and again stop recording if I touch the region again.

I have prerequisite knowledge of the pyautogui module which enables me to define a square region with the desired coordinates. Just need a method to identify a touch or mouse click event.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've tried running the code given in the link. Given the complexity of the code and being new to PyAudio, it was a little difficult to understand how things like "chunks", "samples" were used. I know I need to understand how the algorithm works there to be able to make what I asked here... yet if I get straight answer here I can compare it with the code in the link above and exactly understand which code does what.